# MongoDB - How to convert every date-field in an array of objects?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I Have a bunch of sensordata stored in mongoDB. They are stored like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "date": ISODate("2020-02-08T18:06:25.507+00:00"),
      "temperature": 20.3,
      "humidity":  53.7
    },
    {
      "date": ISODate("2020-02-08T18:07:25.507+00:00"),
      "temperature": 21,
      "humidity":  54
    }
  ]
}
```

The day-field is generated by `new Date()` with JavaScript.
Now i just want the get all the data and convert the "date"-field to a time-field. The result should look like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "date": "18:06:25",
      "temperature": 20.3,
      "humidity":  53.7
    },
    {
      "date": "18:07:25",
      "temperature": 21,
      "humidity":  54
    }
  ]
}
```

So is there a way to convert every "date"-field in the array to a "time"-field by using `db.collection.aggregate`?

I tried using this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
        {},
        {
          "$project": {
            "data.date": { $dateToString: { format: "%H:%M:%S",date: "$date" } },
            "daydata.temperature": 1,
            "daydata.humidity": 1
          }
        }
      ])
```

I know it doesnt work, because i dont have any "date"-field outside of "data". But i dont know **how to reach the date-field of every data-object and convert it**.

Comment: If your dates are stored as `"date": "2020-02-08T18:06:25.507+00:00"` wouldn't you just need to truncate the string?  The date operations like `$dateToString` don't work on string values.

Comment: A bit "forth and back" but try `data.date": { $dateToString: { format: "%H:%M:%S",date: {$dateFromString: {dateString:"$date"} } }`

Comment: sadly this "easy" way doenst work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $unwind then $project then $group in aggregate.

```
db.data.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$data" },
  {
    $project: {
      "data.date": {
        $dateToString: { format: "%H:%M:%S", date: "$data.date" },
      },
      "data.temperature": 1,
      "data.humidity": 1,
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      data: { $push: "$data" },
    },
  },
]);
```

Also, date should be ISODate

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "date": ISODate("2020-02-08T18:06:25.507+00:00"),
      "temperature": 20.3,
      "humidity":  53.7
    },
    {
      "date": ISODate("2020-02-08T18:07:25.507+00:00"),
      "temperature": 21,
      "humidity":  54
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `data.date` field is a string, use the sub-string operator to extract the time part of the date field.

```
db.test.aggregate( [
  { 
      $unwind: "$data" 
  },
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          "data.time": { $substrCP: [ "$data.date", 11, 8 ] } 
      }
  },
  { 
      $project: { "data.date": 0 }
  },
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: "$_id", 
          data: { $push: "$data" },  
          // other_fld: { $first: "$other_fld" }
       } 
  }
] ).pretty()
```